# Why the output of .splice is a single object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am working on my API. At this point, I want to replace the first object of an array such as:

**If given data is:**

```
const data = ["1", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

then I want:
**OUTPUT AS:**

```
["New_text", 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

For this, I tried .splice function:

```
const new_data = data.splice(0, 1, "New_text")
```

But I am getting ["1"] as output. How can I do this?

Comment: do you want a new array?

Comment: [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) return value is "An array containing the deleted elements", `data` is modified in-place.

Comment: you re fine, just remove now the last element of data

Comment: @Nick I knew where I was wrong because of your comment. Thank you. I just realize I have to console.log(data).

Comment: Why not just do `data[0] = "New_text"`

Comment: Splice give you Array with only the deleted items

Answer (score 2):

`splice` method return a new array of deleted items. It also mutates the original array

Try

```js
const data = ['1', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
data.splice(0, 1);
data.unshift('New_text');
console.log(data);
```

Comment: You need to add ```data.pop()``` before ```console.log```

Comment: Isn't `data[0] = "New_text"` simpler than using 2 array extension methods?

Answer (score 1):

It is working correctly but you are misunderstanding how it works:

```
const deleted_data = data.splice(0, 1, "New_text");
console.log(deleted_data); // [1]
console.log(data);         // ["New_text", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
//            ^
//            |
//   NOTE: "data" itself is modified by splice
```

If you really want to insist that the added data be part of a new array you need to manually copy the old array to a new array:

```
const new_data = data.slice(); // copy old array
new_data.splice(0, 1, "New_text");
//   ^
//   |
// NOTE: new_data, not data !
```

Answer (score 1):

the splice method works fine for you. but if the task is only to change first element in array you actually instead of splice can use this

```
const data = ["1", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
data.shift()
data.unshift("New_text")
// or just 
data[0] = "New_text"
```

Answer (score 0):

splice make a new array made with the items you deleted ONLY.

you need to put the new 'New_text' in the original array After using splice,

try unshift method to put 'New_text' as the first element.